# Pandas, How to reference Timeseries Items?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I'm trying to work with some stock market data. I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> ticker
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 707 entries, 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2012-10-19 00:00:00
Data columns:
Open         707  non-null values
High         707  non-null values
Low          707  non-null values
Close        707  non-null values
Volume       707  non-null values
Adj Close    707  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
```

I'll reference a random closing price:

```
>>> ticker ['Close'] [704]
21.789999999999999
```

What's the syntax to get the date of that 704th item?

Similarly, how do I get the position in the array of the following item?:

```
>>> ticker.Close.min ()
17.670000000000002
```

I know this seems pretty basic, but I've spent a lot of time scouring the documentation. If it's there, I'm absolutely missing it.

Comment: There is a tutorial lecture which maybe help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0unf-C-pBYE

Answer (score 3):

This should answer both your questions:

Note: if you want the 704th element, you should use "703" as index starts form zero. As you see `df['A'].argmin()` also returns 1, that is the second row in the df.

```
In [682]: print df
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01  1.073247 -1.784255  0.137262
2000-01-02 -0.797483  0.665392  0.692429
2000-01-03  0.123751  0.532109  0.814245
2000-01-04  1.045414 -0.687119 -0.451437
2000-01-05  0.594588  0.240058 -0.813954
2000-01-06  1.104193  0.765873  0.527262
2000-01-07 -0.304374 -0.894570 -0.846679
2000-01-08 -0.443329 -1.437305 -0.316648


In [683]: df.index[3]
Out[683]: <Timestamp: 2000-01-04 00:00:00>

In [684]: df['A'].argmin()
Out[684]: 1
```