# Get Date of last record in Date indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am reading an End of Day price csv file and use the date column to index the dataframe.  I want to check the date of the last record.  I get the index value location, but have not figured out how to get the actual date.

CSV file has format of Date, Open, High, Low, ....

Here Date is in the form 2014-07-28.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('c:/datafile.csv', index_col='Date')
lastrec = len(df.index) -1

# how to get 'Date' Value for this last record?
df.iloc[lastrec]
# gives me the Open, High, .... columns and values

df.iloc[lastrec].index 
# gives me the list of columns
```

All my other ideas have just given me errors.

Still learning Python and Pandas by doing this project.

How can I get the index value (DATE) from the last record?

Answer (score 1):

Without having to get `lastrec` first:

```
df.index[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas, How to reference Timeseries Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992958/pandas-how-to-reference-timeseries-items)

So in your example:

```
df.index[lastrec]
# gives me the date 2014-07-28 as desired.
```